# Two-party symmetric key establishment protocol

Tags: authentication, key-exchange

I need a symmetric key protocol that will mutually authenticate and establish a new short-living session key between two parties that have a pre-shared key. Unfortunately, I have not found any existing protocol that would fit my purposes, so I quickly devised my own. Would greatly appreciate your feedback on the protocol, or otherwise any advice to find something that already exists.

Notation:

```
C         = Client
S         = Server
K         = pre-shared key between C and S
ENC(K, m) = message m encrypted with key K; encryption function is AES-256-CBC
MAC(K, m) = a message-authentication code of message m, computed using key K
rnd       = random value
c1        = client challenge (randomly generated by the client)
c2        = server challenge (randomly generated by the server)
K'        = short-living session key
```

The protocol:

```
C -> S : em = ENC(K, (rnd, c1)), MAC(K, em)
S -> C : em = ENC(K, (c2,  c1)), MAC(K, em)
C -> S : em = ENC(K, (c1,  c2)), MAC(K, em)
```

Further session messages are encrypted with session key K' = c1 + K + c2:

```
* -> * : em = ENC(K', m), MAC(K', em)
```

**Rationale for using PSK instead of private/public keys**.
Simplicity of usage. A tool is run on a server, and generates a unique PSK automatically, which the user then needs to manually or programmatically transfer to the clients he wants to connect. For the user this is much easier than using public-key cryptography.

**Rationale for having session keys in addition to PSK**.
In the system I am working on, A PSK establishes a limited-time trust between a server and multiple clients. The underlying protocol is for configuration management, and there should be a protection against replay attacks. **IF** I were just to use the same PSK to encrypt different sessions, **THEN** it could be possible, as far as I see, just to record and then replay a session to achieve another (unauthorized) configuration update, which would be bad. Usage of session keys precludes this scenario.

**P.S.** I am asking this question here after I've asked the same on security.stackexchange, and was pointed out that cryptography.stackexchange might be a better fit. People there also pointed out that TLS-PSK protocol might fit my purposes; would appreciate your comments on that as well. It might also be that I am totally overcomplicating the things, will be grateful for any simplification suggestions!

Comment: As correctly pointed out on securitySE the TLS protocol would fit. Also: You should *never* use your own protocol, that's bad practice in cryptography.

Comment: Also if you look hard enough there are (proven-secure) PSK protocols beyond what TLS offers. Of course implementations of these tend to be less common...

Comment: What you want is PSK authenticated asymmetric key exchange. TLS has a mode for this, SSH can do it (with plugins for SRP type protocols), among others.